# iron router only works with one route

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to have more than one page on my meteor application, I'm running meteor 1.3.1 and the latest iron router.

This is my main.js file.

```
Router.route('/home', function () {
  this.render('home');
});
Router.route('/register', function () {
  this.render('register');
});
```

This is my main.html file

```
<template name="home">
    <h1>Hello there !</h1>
</template>
<template name="about">
    <h1>this is an about page!</h1>
</template>
<template name="register">
    <h2>Register</h2>
</template>
```

Now if I navigate to `http://localhost:3000/home` I can see `hello there!`

But if I navigate to `http://localhost:3000/register` I see 
`Oops, looks like there's no route on the client or the server for url: "http://localhost:3000/register."`

However if I switch the position of routes in the js file to this:

```
Router.route('/register', function () {
  this.render('register');
});
Router.route('/home', function () {
  this.render('home');
});
```

then the register page works and the home page doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it turns out that it didn't work because i was using chrome canary (experimental version of chrome), upon using google chrome it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `Router.map` syntax instead:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('home', {path: '/home',});
  this.route('register', {path: '/register',});
});
```